# Why isn't this Alarm Manager code not working?

Tags: android, kotlin, debugging, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I've been trying to implement alarm manager in andriod studio with Kotlin and it just isn't isn't working for me. Can any of you point my in the right direction?

[My alarm manager code]

```
        val context: Context = this

        alarmManager = context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
        val intent = Intent(context, AlarmFire::class.java)

         pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
       // val omega = (0..59).random()

        val calendar : Calendar= Calendar.getInstance()
        calendar.timeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,18)
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,14)
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,0)
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.timeInMillis, pendingIntent)
```

[Manifest]

```
<receiver android:name=".AlarmFire"
android:enabled="true"
android:exported="true">
</receiver>
```

[My AlarmFire class]

```
class AlarmFire : BroadcastReceiver(){
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {

        Toast.makeText(context, "Refreshing Webview", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)


    }
}
```

Comment: Can you put codes instead images

Comment: Did you test on emulator ?

Comment: @TicherhazFreePalestine yea, I've tried testing this numerous times...

Comment: Try this, once you pressed RUN , it will open the apps, and then clear the apps , and then open it the apps back through emulator phone. NOT RUN

Comment: @TicherhazFreePalestine Yea it still doesn't work... I actually can't figure out whats wrong with my code either...

Comment: Did you check time to trigger, is it correct?

Comment: @TicherhazFreePalestine , Well I've tried putting in times close to mine just like 1-5 minutes ahead, For example: I tried putting 20:10, when it was currently 20:05 in my time. Does this code work for you?

Comment: Use `alarmManager.setExact` instead of `set`. Otherwise you'll need to wait 15 minutes or so past the requested time to be sure if it's going to fire.